# Can I use the eval function in this case?

Tags: php, eval

how could I get the following code to print out aaa.bbb.ccc ??
Currently all I get is a parse error for each eval() line.
This is a abstract code version. Finally I want the users to be able to select fields of a database table to be searched through. Something like a combination of 
if (strpos("$field1.$field2.$field3",$search) !== false) ...

```
$filter = "\$x=\$a.\$b.\$c";

$a = "a";
$b = "a";
$c = "a";
eval($filter);
echo $x.",";

$a = "b";
$b = "b";
$c = "b";
eval($filter);
echo $x.",";

$a = "c";
$b = "c";
$c = "c";
eval($filter);
echo $x;
```

Comment: Why do you use `\$x`? Second - `eval` is EVIL.

Comment: Found my simple error: I forgot the ';'. $filter must be "\$x=\$a.\$b.\$c;"; I have to escape the $ otherwise the content of $x would be used and it would not be an expression for eval()

Comment: And why does concatenation need `eval`? `$x = $a . $b . $c;`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your current code, change the following:

```
$filter = "\$x=\$a.\$b.\$c";
```

To

```
$filter = '$x=$a.$b.$c;';
```

But to use `eval()` on user input is a big security hole in your code. Try some different approach, like checking if the input is present in `$search` by use of a regular expression and the `preg_match_all()` function.